# Get log of commits since split off parent branch including the parent branch's latest commit

Tags: git

I'm trying to make a quick bash function that returns a `--oneline` log of every commit since the current branch was branched off of its parent, and *including* the line for that previous commit.  Here is what I have so far.

```bash
# stolen from another Stack Overflow question
__git__get_parent_branch() {
  echo $(git show-branch 2>/dev/null |
    sed "s/].*//" |
    grep "\*" |
    grep -v "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" |
    head -n1 |
    sed "s/^.*\[//" |
    sed "s/[\^\~].*$//")
}

lp() {
  if [[ $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) = master ]]; then
    echo Already on master branch.
    return 1
  fi

  local commits="$(git log --oneline $(git merge-base $(__git__get_parent_branch) HEAD)..HEAD)"
  [[ -z $commits ]] && 1>&2 echo No commits since $(__git__get_parent_branch). || echo -e "$commits"
}
```

This correctly gets every commit *after* the parent's commit.  I had thought I could just append `^` or `~1` to the `git merge-base` result:

```bash
local commits="$(git log --oneline $(git merge-base $(__git__get_parent_branch) HEAD)^..HEAD)"

# or
local commits="$(git log --oneline $(git merge-base $(__git__get_parent_branch) HEAD)~1..HEAD)"
```

However, this doesn't seem to work if the branched SHA was of a merge.  Since most of my branches are off of `master`, this will always be the case.  Instead of showing the merge SHA, it shows every entry since the first commit of that merge.  If a merge contained two commits, I see the lines I want to see, plus two additional ones I don't want.

I believe the crux of this problem is that `^` and `~1` don't do quite what I want.

(I also see that my `[[ -z $commits ]]` won't work if I achieve this, but that's something I can solve later.)

Edit: Perhaps the simplest solution is just to retrieve and append the line directly.

```bash
local parent="$(__git__get_parent_branch)"
local commits="$(git log --oneline $(git merge-base $parent HEAD)..HEAD)
$(git log --oneline -1 $parent)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `^@`, which is [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) syntax for "all parents of the commit".