# Show commits since branching from parent branch?

Tags: git, branch, commit

### The question

Is there a way to list all the commits done on current branch only since it has been branched from its parent?

#### Example

Let's say I'm on my `master` branch and made commits `A` and `B`, then branch to a new `feature-branch` and made commits `C` and `D`: is there a way to list only `C` and `D`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get log of commits since split off parent branch including the parent branch's latest commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66587996/get-log-of-commits-since-split-off-parent-branch-including-the-parent-branchs-l)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git doesn't remember parent branches, or where a branch started, but you probably do:

> Let's say I'm on my `master` ... then [create] `feature-branch` and made commits `C` and `D`: is there a way to list only `C` and `D`?

The `git log` command will show commits that are in some selected *range* of commits, if you use the `b1..b2` syntax, which is short for `b2 --not b1`.  Here you'd want:

```
git log feature-branch --not master
```

or:

```
git log master..feature-branch
```

or:

```
git log master..HEAD
```

or:

```
git log master..
```

The way this works internally is that Git will, temporarily, "paint certain commits red" (for STOP) and other commits "green" (for GO).  The "green paint" starts with the commits you say you want: `HEAD` or `feature-branch` for instance.  It then floods "backwards" from commit to parent-commit.

The "red paint" starts with the commits you say to reject: `master`, or commit `B` in this case.  It then floods "backwards" from commit to parent-commit.

The red "overrides" the green, or equivalently, we do the red first and don't re-paint a commit.  So given that we have:

```
A <-B   <-- master
     \
      C <-D   <-- feature-branch (HEAD)
```

this "paints `B` and `A` red" and "paints `C` and `D` green" and hence the commits you'll see listed are `D` and then `C` (in that order due to the git log graph-walk order).

The `master..` syntax is short for `master..HEAD`: any time you leave a name off one side of the two-dot syntax, it means `HEAD`.

If we add more commits to `master` (and then go back to `feature-branch`):

```
A <-B <-E <-F <-G <-H  <-- master
     \
      C <-D   <-- feature-branch (HEAD)
```

the "red paint" now starts at `H` and works its way back to `B`, so this still works.

Note: this two-dot syntax works with many Git commands and usually means this same thing.  However, for `git diff`, it doesn't: `git diff master..feature-branch` just means *find the commit that `master` points to* and *find the commit that `feature-branch` points to*—which in this case would be `B` and `D`, or later, `H` and `D`—and diff those two commits.  That is, `git diff X..Y` and `git diff X Y` are entirely identical.

(There's also a three-dot syntax, and it has one meaning for most Git commands and different and special meaning for `git diff`.  So `git diff` is a little weird overall.)

Answer (score 0):

According to what you are saying, you should be using cherry and here is the documentation for a more in-depth look about it: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry

The command that should show you what you are looking for:

```
git cherry -v <parent_branch> <targeted_branch>
# Given your example: git cherry -v master feature-branch
```

Explanation:

This would display all commits contained in <targeted_branch> and especially not from the <parent_branch>. Additionally, if the final parameter is omitted, the current branch will be compared instead. (See the documentation above for more detailed).

Comment: `git cherry` is specifically useful after using `git cherry-pick`. Otherwise a simple `git log` suffices. Note that `git cherry` uses the three-dot notation plus some additional internal magic in the revision walk code.